# Revenue cat User is ineligible for that action. & User is ineligible for promotional offer

Tags: swift, revenuecat

I have an `Appstore` autorenewing subscription with an offer attached, which I can successfully fetch with the `SKProduct`.discounts, but when I try to get the `SKPaymentDiscount` with this code:

```
Purchases.shared.paymentDiscount
```

I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=RCPurchasesErrorDomain Code=18 "The User is ineligible for that action." UserInfo={readable_error_code=INELIGIBLE_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=The User is ineligible for that action., NSUnderlyingError=0x283e77f30 {Error Domain=RCBackendErrorDomain Code=7232 "User is ineligible for promotional offer." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=User is ineligible for promotional offer.}}}
```

Any kind of help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out this wasn't a problem on revenue cats side. I just didn't realise that new users weren't eligible for promotion offers, only introductory offers.